# MOSFET current at very low temperature (4K)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, electric-current, semiconductor-physics, low-temperature-physics

I am trying to model the current at low T. To do so I need to compute the integral of  fermi dirac statistics multiplied by the conductivity, with respect to energy:

[image]
[image]
[image]

My problem is that I cannot understand how can I have something different than 0 for a PMOS as my functions seems totally disconnected in the sens that if one is not zero, the other one is :

[image]

I guess I am missing something but I cannot see it..

**EDIT :** Just figured out that for PMOS, the band edge considered for the conductivity computation is the one of the valence band and not the conduction band right ? So I don't know if :

-I should replace Fermi-Dirac with 1 - Fermi-Dirac as I am considering holes

-How to adapt the conductivity function that is proportional to ln(1+exp(E-Ec)*a) : does it work if I replace E-Ec by Ev-E ?

Comment: Both functions look non-zero though. Are you trying to compute the integral graphically?

Comment: @Vadim when doing FD*conductivity, it gives something very close to 0 for all E.. No, I compute the integral numerically but I was trying to understand what was going on and I find it easier with graph.

Answer (score 0):

It could be helpful to write the functions explicitly - both are not zero in the whole range, so your problems are of numerical nature. It is also helpful to plot their product, i.e., the integrand. Mathematically the problem comes from the fact that the Fermi function is exponentionally vanishing above the Fermi level, whereas your conductivity exponentially vanishes at small values. There is however a small peak in between, which needs to be integrated with high resolution. It is hard to say more without more details.

**Update**
With the equations added: the problem is calculating integrals of type
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dE \frac{\log\left(1+e^{\frac{E}{\Delta E}}\right)}{1+e^{\frac{E-E_F}{k T}}}
$$
The integral suffers from the fact that the numerator goes to zero for $E\rightarrow -\infty$, whereas for $E\rightarrow +\infty$ it behaves as $E/\Delta E$. In addition it contains exponents that may produce *numerical zeros* when the numbers are smaller than the numerical precision.

With substitution $x=e^{\frac{E}{k T}}$ we can reduce it to
$$
I = zk T\int_0^{+\infty}dx \frac{\log\left(1+x^{\frac{kT}{\Delta E}}\right)}{x(z+x)},
$$
where we defined $z=\exp{\frac{E_F}{kT}}$.

Alternatively, one could use substitution $x=e^{\frac{E}{\Delta E}}$, when we get
$$
I = zk T\int_0^{+\infty}dx \frac{\log\left(1+x\right)}{x(z+x^{\frac{\Delta E}{kT}})},
$$
Which of tehse is easier to calculate depends on the ratio of parameters $kT$ and $\Delta E$.

Comment: I've added them :) I think my problem is that I have used the conductivity and FD stat for electrons while being in a PMOS, I am not sure how to adapt them

Comment: I am now not sure what exactly you need help with - choosing the right formulas or calculating the integral?

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear, I would like to adapt the formulas, I will compute the integral using python

Comment: I added a few tips. But please check my calculations before applying them.